# JProgressBar with double value

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

Hello i would like to know if i can extends a `JProgressBar` to use double value for min max, instead of int.
Thank you.

Comment: I would not extend it, but wrap it.

Answer (score 6):

If you know the bounds and precision of your values, it's quite easy to do with a wrapper. I've used this approach for a computationally intensive application where 1% equates to about 30 seconds. Showing a `JProgressBar` with `min=0` and `max=100` didn't give enough feedback. Users thought the application was hung.

Solution: Scale the values

I had a float (0f - 1f) that represented the actual percent complete. 
By multiplied that by 10000 I got an integer range of 0 - 10000. I set up JPB with min=0 and max=10000.

Then just a call to `setString(NumberFormat.getPercentInstance().format(value))` to display the formatted percent.

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can, but for what purpose? How do you display a half percent?

You can however use the [setString()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setString%28java.lang.String%29)-method to display the more exact value. Printing the String must be turned on using the [setStringPainted()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setStringPainted%28boolean%29)-method.

Comment: If your progress bar is 400 pixels wide, you show half a percent as two pixels. It gives fine-grained resolution when you have more information.

Comment: @Kieveli i see your point, but this works with normal integers as well. If you want the progressbar to be the most fine-grained, you set the maximum to your highest possible value. The bar will take care of drawing as fine as it can.

Comment: I believe I was missing the point of setting the bar from 0-10000 instead of 0-100.  Effectively, 0-10000 gives you potential render precision of two decimal places - assuming you have a crazy wide pixel count.